# Pipes para checkbox Contact Form 7

Tags: checkbox, wordpress

Preciso adaptar um checkbox do plugin Contact Form 7 do wordpress com pipes, o que estou fazendo:

Meu **shortcode** no formulário:

```
[checkbox checkbox-579 "10 cm" "15 cm" "20 cm" "30 cm"]
```

E tenho de resultado:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-579[]" value="10 cm">
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">10 cm</span>
...
```

Quero que fique com um valor no **checkbox** e um para a `span`, tentei algo como:

```
[checkbox checkbox-579 "10 cm|3000" "15 cm|3017" "20 cm|2362" "30 cm|2379"]
```

Mas o resultado não mudou. Preciso que fique assim:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-579[]" value="3000">
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">10 cm</span>
...
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer por esse meio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema definindo os inputs diretamente na configuração do módulo, contatei o criador do módulo que pareceu ter descaso com a questão, inclusive se encontram diversos questionamentos sobre esse problema no fórum de discussão do plugin.

**Pipes** só funcionam com **selects**.

A solução:

```
<label> Nome (obrigatório)</label>
    [text* t_name] </label>

<label> E-mail (obrigatório)</label>
    [email* mail]

<label> Telefone</label>
    [text tel]

<label>Alturas Disponíveis</label>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-579"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-579[]" value="3000">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">10cm</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-579[]" value="3017">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">15cm</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-579[]" value="2362">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">20cm</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-579[]" value="2379">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">30cm</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>

<div class="colors clear">
                <strong>Selecione as Cores</strong>
                <ul class="colores">
                  <li class="select_cor Amarelo" title="Amarelo"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Azul_Claro" title="Azul Claro"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Azul_Escuro" title="Azul Escuro"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Branco" title="Branco"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Laranja" title="Laranja"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Lilas" title="Lilas"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Marfim" title="Marfim"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Marrom" title="Marrom"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Pink" title="Pink"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Preto" title="Preto"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Verde" title="Verde"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Verde_Limao" title="Verde Limão"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Vermelho" title="Vermelho"></li>
                  <li class="select_cor Rosa" title="Rosa"></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

[hidden cores class:hidden_cores]
<label> Quantidade</label>
    [text quantidade]
<label>Observações</label>
    [textarea mensagem] 

[submit "Enviar"]
```

E no e-mail basta definir os campos normalmente:

```
De: [t_name] <[mail]>

Telefone: [tel]

Cores: [cores]

Códigos: [checkbox-579]

Quantidade: [quantidade]

Corpo da mensagem:
[mensagem]
```